# Issue with Embedded Video Playback on Mobile Devices After Seraphinite Accelerator wordpress plugin Integration

Tags: wordpress, plugins, divi, accelerator

I have identified a challenge related to displaying embedded videos on mobile screens following the implementation of the Seraphinite Accelerator plugin. The embedded video no longer plays automatically as before the plugin integration. It works properly for the desktop screen.
This is the website that I currently working on. `https://cgistudio.at/`